# How to find a specific folder?

Tags: vba, outlook, directory

I have a sub to read/get the email items in a specific folder.

It doesn't find the folder.

```
Sub HowManyEmails()

    Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim EmailCount As Integer
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder = objnSpace.folders("#MemoScan")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "No such folder."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count

    MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount, , "email count"

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

It returns the built-in message "No such folder.".

My folder structure:
[image]

How can I get that folder?

Comment: You might actually check Err.Number to determine what is being returned. You might also check to see whether objFolder contains an object reference or truly is "nothing". The failure may or may not be due to the inability to find the target folder. Right now, you're *assuming* the failure is "not found." It might not be.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049546/get-mapi-folder-in-outlook-from-folder-path

Comment: @DavidW I printed the error which was: `The operation failed. Can't find a object`. When checking the objFolder in the debugger, it returns `Nothing`.

Comment: @Nicolas Good enough. I'd try changing the path to the folders call to "#MemoScan/Inbox" and see if that helps.

Comment: Figured it out thanks to Kaybee99's link. It seemed that the folder first had to look for `William` and then for the `#MemoScan` folder! Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to the following link:
[Get MAPI Folder in Outlook from Folder Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049546/get-mapi-folder-in-outlook-from-folder-path).

By right clicking on the folder I could see the actual location was on William and not directly on the folder. So the right code is:

`Set objFolder = objnSpace.folders("William").folders("#MemoScan")`