# Specifying an email address and non-default folder name if I have more than one email address in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The following code is working, but I have a few questions.

1. I have more than one email address in Outlook. I would like to specify the email address in Excel. Let's say in "Control" tab, cell "b1" is an email address. How can I specify it?
2. I want to specify a non-default folder name (not Inbox, Sent, Drafts or Delete) by name in Excel. Let’s say in the "Control" tab, cell "c1" is a folder name. How can I specify it?

```vb
Sub GetFromInbox()
    
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Namespace
    Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
    Dim olMail As Variant
    Dim i, ij As Integer
    Dim tt As Date
    
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    i = 1
    ij = 0
    x = Date
    
    ' Now. the following "For each next " code starts to look in the oldest email!
    ' So how can I change the code if the code starts from the newest?
    For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
        ij = ij + 1
        'If IsNumeric((Format(olMail.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yy"))) Then
            Sheets("test").Range("a1").Select
            Sheets("test").Range("I1").Clear
            Sheets("test").Range("I2") = ij
            Sheets("test").Range("I1").Value = (Format(olMail.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yy"))
            Sheets("test").Range("I1").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
            tt = Sheets("test").Range("I1")
            ' MsgBox ("Y-tt=" & tt & " receivedtime=" & olMail.ReceivedTime)
        'Else
            'tt = 0
            'MsgBox ("N-tt=" & tt & " receivedtime=" & olMail.ReceivedTime)
        'End If
        ' tt = CDate(Format(olMail.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yy"))
        If tt >= Range("H1") Then
            'If InStr(olMail.Subject, "others") > 0 And tt >= Range("h1") Then
            If InStr(olMail.Subject, "others") > 0 Then
                ActiveSheet.Range("h2") = "y"
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = olMail.Subject
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = olMail.ReceivedTime
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = olMail.SenderName
                tt = CDate(Format(olMail.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yy"))
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = CDate(Format(olMail.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yy"))
                ' tt = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = (Format(olMail.ReceivedTime, "hh:mm"))
                MsgBox ("tt=" & tt)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Else
            Sheets("test").Range("h2") = "N"
        End If
    Next olMail
    
    Set Fldr = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    'tt = ""
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox)

Comment: I checked it and it wont help a lot

Comment: Let say this way  : I have 4 email address in outlook and different name of the folders . So in  "Main" tab ,  cell (A2) is for me to type email address. cell(b2) is for me to type folder name. Everytime if I need to extract some email (by using the above VBA code), i can be flexible by typing email address in cell (A2) and folder name in cell(b2)  to extract it. So how can I change the above code to cope with that?

Answer (score 0):

This describes how to walk from folder to folder.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35657225/1571407

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration

Sub GetFromAdditionalInbox()

    ' Early binding. Set reference to Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Namespace
    Dim Fldr As Outlook.folder

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' Where folders are in the navigation pane
    '
    ' In "Main" tab
    '  - cell (A2) is email address.
    '  - cell (B2) is "Inbox"
    '  - cell (C2) is "subfolder directly under Inbox"
    '  - cell (D2) is "subsubfolder directly under subfolder"
    '
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")

        ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox
        Set Fldr = olNs.Folders(.Range("A2").Value)
        Set Fldr = Fldr.Folders(.Range("B2").Value)
        'Set Fldr = Fldr.Folders(.Range("C2").Value)
        'Set Fldr = Fldr.Folders(.Range("D2").Value)

        ' If the tree goes much further, investigate GetFolder
        '  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049546/get-mapi-folder-in-outlook-from-folder-path

    End With

    Debug.Print Fldr

End Sub
```

Comment: State what you see in the immediate pane for `Debug.Print Fldr`. Should be "Inbox". If you do not get that far, what is the error and the line with the error?

Comment: I think cell(A2) is for me to put the email address. Cell(B2) is the name of the folder. The folder is not default ( i.e. inbox/sent/ deleted) but it could be any name that I created.  For the email address (bc2@abc.com)  , it is group email address and can read/move email under this email address but could not use this email to anyone

Comment: it stopped working at this one -->Set Fldr = olNs.Folders(.Range("A2").Value)

Comment: If bc2@abc.com is the text displayed in the navigation pane then there is nothing I can think of.

Comment: niton: I found the way out.  -- set fldr=session.folders(worksheets("main").range("A2").Value).folders(worksheets("main").range("B2").Value)   <--A2 is not the email address but the name of email address. Let say this way-->the name is T123 and email address is T123.b123@abc.com

Comment: so I will have to put <T123> into cell A2